Pylance failing to resolve import of libraries in a devcontainer in Linux
I have a Python project in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I have a DevContainer in VSC with Debian GNU/Linux 11, the problem is that Pylance is flagging import streamlit as st with Import "streamlit" could not be resolved. If I run the application from the terminal with streamlit run myfile.py, it runs perfectly, but launching the debugger raises this exception:
EDIT I reset the Docker image, and the exception changed to a simpler one:
/usr/bin/python3: No module named streamlit

This is my devcontainer.json:
{
    "build": {"dockerfile": "Dockerfile"},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
            ]
        },
        "forwardPorts": [8501],
        "runArgs": ["--env-file",".devcontainer/devcontainer.env"]
    }
}

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install oscrypto@git+https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto.git@d5f3437ed24257895ae1edd9e503cfb352e635a8

# COPY src ./src
# WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH=/workspaces/my_project/src

EXPOSE 8001
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "view/frontend/main.py"]

And this is my launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"}
        },
        {
            "name": "Python:Streamlit",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "${file}",
                "--server.port",
                "8501",
                "--server.fileWatcherType",
                "poll",
                "--server.address",
                "0.0.0.0"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "PYTHONHOME": "/usr/local/bin"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have tried a lot of configurations, but I failed to find one that works.
EDIT
I have pylance and streamlit workinng together in another computer with a VSC Dev Container over Windows, and they work perfectly.
This is what I get with python -m site:
sys.path = [
    '/workspaces/sacbeh',
    '/workspaces/sacbeh/src',
    '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True


Yeah, it's unclear what's going on there.
I can easily reproduce such behavior with python 3.13.0 under macOS.
$ cat st.py && python st.py && echo && pyright st.py
import streamlit
print('Hello, world!')

Hello, world!

st.py:1:8 - error: Import "streamlit" could not be resolved (reportMissingImports)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations 

solution
I recommend you move on to
another linter
when working with streamlit:
$ mypy st.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

It also accepts switches like --ignore-missing-imports if you
continue to run into trouble.
I usually find it most helpful when executed using --strict.


But, does this solve the debugging error, or just the linting

There's two questions posed.
I answered the first one, by suggesting the use of a non-broken linter.
In a subsequent edit you explained

I reset the Docker image, and the exception changed to a simpler one:
/usr/bin/python3: No module named streamlit

Well, that seems pretty straightforward to fix.
I don't know what the verb "reset" means here,
but the symptom shows that "broke" is an appropriate verb.
Your sys.path is not pointing at a venv with streamlit installed.
(Or, IDK maybe you're shooting for system level library installs,
and streamlit isn't installed.
Yeah, RUN pip install ... -r requirements.txt
looks like it uses a system-wide folder such as /usr/local.
It's not obvious to me how the interpreter in /usr/bin
is going to find /usr/local folders.
I usually rely on python -m venv and then source activate,
but you have gone down a different config path in your container.)
It's easy enough to fix up "missing deps".
Start with $ which python to verify that the interpreter
you think is running truely is the one that does run.
Then $ python -m site offers a convenient way to
see which directories import consults.
Adjust the PYTHONPATH env var if your favorite folder is missing.
Sometimes $ which pip shows it is coming from a different place.
Installing deps with $ python -m pip install streamlit foo bar baz
is more robust, as the install is guaranteed to use the same interpreter
and same venv as the execution environment.
Running
$ find /workspaces/sacbeh /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages |
    grep streamlit

should reveal where pip installed the library.
If it is absent, then streamlit imports won't succeed.
(BTW, USER_BASE and USER_SITE not existing is definitely
not a problem, don't worry about that.)

If code runs fine from ENTRYPOINT or a bash prompt,
but not from an IDE, one can always use the stopgap
of inserting a breakpoint() call in the code,
until the IDE can be coaxed into working again.
An if statement can even conditionally enter
the standard debugger.

But, does this solve the debugging error, or just the linting flag?

Well, I did it, but the debugger is still raising the same error.

With "reset" I mean I rebuild the docker image. I think the issue is in the VSC configuration system since the command line launch of streamlit inside the running container works smoothly. it is only the VSC debugger what fails with the error

It's unclear what "the debugger" means here, and why it would be relevant. First things first: you need to ensure that $ python -c 'import streamlit' succeeds, that is, you need a usable venv which pip can successfully install packages into. Did you insert a breakpoint() statement and that blew up? Is the pycharm graphical IDE not putting the little red dot for a breakpoint in the right spot? With no successful install of the streamlit library, I don't see how the other details would even matter yet.

I don't use the VSC debugger. I can tell you that it, or any similar python based tool, will attempt to import your code. And if the streamlit library isn't available, there will be no joy in Mudville. The python -m site debugging technique will likely reveal the trouble most quickly. Or run some import sys; print(sys.path) code manually.

As I stated in the body of the question, all this happens inside a VSC Docker dev container that is build automatically by VSC using a devcontainer configuration set of files. Streamlit is propperly imported since the code runs smoothly when executed from the commandline, but when I push VSC debugger, I get the error

Your OP boiled down to "pyright doesn't work with streamlit", and I agreed with you, I showed how to reproduce same symptom in a quite different environment. You can try to make those two work together. I predict you will get type checking to work more quickly if you opt for mypy.

Thanks a lot, but my minor concern is the linter (I referenced the issue in case it is related to the debugger error), what I really need the most is the debugger to run as well as the command line call works.
